# How to have a guest user after log in retain his data with Devise + Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, e-commerce

As by the Devise docs that are so often referred to ([Found here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user)), I made this `application_controller.rb` for an e-commerce platform:

```ruby
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...

  # The order that can be used in the shop up untill the point of payment.
  def current_order
    if current_user
      current_order = Order.where(customer_id: current_user.id, status: :open).first_or_create(status: :open)
    else
      current_order = Order.where(customer_id: guest_user.id).first_or_create(status: :open)
    end
  end

  ##### From Devise documentation: guest user #####
  def current_or_guest_user
    if current_user
      if session[:guest_user_id] && session[:guest_user_id] != current_user.id
        logging_in
        guest_user(with_retry = false).reload.try(:destroy)
        session[:guest_user_id] = nil
      end
      current_user
    else
      guest_user
    end
  end

  def guest_user(with_retry = true)
    @cached_guest_user ||= User.find(session[:guest_user_id] ||= create_guest_user.id)

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
     session[:guest_user_id] = nil
     guest_user if with_retry
  end

  private

  # Custom logging in
  def logging_in
    guest_order = current_order
    guest_order.customer.id = current_user.id
    guest_order.save!
  end

  def create_guest_user
    u = User.create(:first_name => "guest", :email => "guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(100)}@example.com")
    u.save!(:validate => false)
    session[:guest_user_id] = u.id
    u
  end

  def store_current_location
    store_location_for(:user, request.url)
  end

  # ...
end
```

Then in my `registrations_controller.rb`:

```ruby
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super
    current_or_guest_user
  end

end
```

And in my `sessions_controller.rb` I have something similar.
In theory this should work.

What happens is that the not-logged-in-user / guest_user goes to check out and sees:

- his order
- a form to register
- a form to log in

Filling in either one of the forms gives me (after a complete rerender)

- his order - still on the guest account!!!
- his profile information
- (and a new form for an address which after filling will make a confirm button show up for proceeding in the payment process.)

Now everything got jammed because the address should be stored as a child on an order that can not be found...

The whole procedure of paying does work when already logged in. The order in the check out view simply already has a `customer_id` of the right user.

Thing is: I want it to work for a user visiting the shop as a guest. I want:

`guest_order = current_order`
`guest_order.customer.id = current_user.id`
`guest_order.save!`

but somehow this code in my `logging_in` doesn't get executed

Comment: Why not store the cart id in a session?

Comment: so the problem is that the user log in and has an empty cart? should he have in his cart the staff added as guest?

Comment: @c0de222 that's is what I'll do when I can't get this to work. Thing is, I simply want a guest user, because it can be useful in more cases.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio exactly, the user should have the stuff in his cart he had before registering.

Comment: I did not work a lot with my devise session controller, you are trying to accomplish this through the session hash? If so would be interesting seeing the value of some of those variables while you debug this scenario, maybe it could give us a better understanding of the real problem

Comment: The problem is exactly as stated above, in my post. I have checked and made really sure that this is what is happening.